# Logging an plotting memory usage from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, memory-management, jupyter-notebook, memory-leaks

I'd like to plot the memory usage over-time at the end of my jupyter notebook, in an automated manner.

I had the habit to do the following:

1. log the memory usage using bash command: basically running a while true code and pipe the output to a text file.
2. read the text file with a specific editor (typically excel for the plots).

However this process is now a bit too manual. I was wondering if there exist a better solution for Jupyter Notebooks, allowing to plot memory consumption of the process. All I can find are command lines or cell magic to perfom the task on a given snippet / cell.

Comment: I think this remains a bit vague as to what you seek still? Do want to run the notebook on the command line and then get the overall result over time? What are the command lines you found not allowing you to do? Or are you wanting to run it in Jupyter and record this. Is the plot to be at the bottom of the Jupyter notebook where you are running code or is it a separate thing? You say you find things but no details here?[This](https://medium.com/@1StepFromMagic/monitoring-of-cpu-and-ram-usage-from-a-jupyter-notebook-f5da263ddbf6) doesn't help get you closer to what you want?

Comment: I'd like to run everything from a notebook; not having to log everything from a second script. Then get the plot at the end. Maybe I just need to launch the script from the notebook. But I was wondering if there are less 'hacky' solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I thought there'd be more along this line but part of the problem is that traditionally you couldn't monitor what you are running as easily within the same notebook. That is why for the visual debugger, special kernel hooks had to be developed. (You can read about some of this [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/a-visual-debugger-for-jupyter-914e61716559) where it talks about the visual debugger first only working with `xeus-python` and [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/enabling-the-jupyterlab-debugger-with-ipykernel-8d7248f522b0) where concurrency is discussed ...

Comment: <continued> to get a better understanding of the limitations that it would be hitting up against having this work in the same notebook.) I wonder if I'm just missing it because it seems the visual debugger approach would then allow what you describe to be done but maybe it just hasn't yet since the debugger itself was such a challenge to develop itself and your idea hasn't been implemented? You can though add times for every cell with an extension, see [jupyterlab-execute-time
](https://github.com/deshaw/jupyterlab-execute-time), but I don't see how to get your plot at the end easily. ...

Comment: <continued> You can do much the same with [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-there-an-option-to-enable-cellmagic-on-every-cell/17852/5?u=fomightez) to add the timeit yourself. But I'm not seeing how to then add that to a plot at the end. Maybe you can just add custom code to the end of every notebook that plots based on those numbers. For another perspective, [perfume](https://github.com/leifwalsh/perfume) looked to be thinking along the way you are but still relied on too much coding of that is being monitored to be very useful. And even worse, has been updated in four years.

Comment: You may be interested in [memray](https://pypi.org/project/memray/). It just got a slew of updates, see [here](https://twitter.com/pyblogsal/status/1742585598571901399). It says it generates reports. And most importantly for you expectations, it has [Jupyter Integration](https://bloomberg.github.io/memray/jupyter_magic.html).  This isn't as all encompassing as that but there is also [pyheatmagic - IPython magic command to profile and view your python code as a heat map](https://github.com/csurfer/pyheatmagic) that I should mention in these comments.